# Why do I have a new Files symbol after opening it?

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher

[How my sidebar normally looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04lci.png) and [How it looks after opening a folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZPF.png)

Why? Normally it was all stacked as one single symbol.

Comment: Please post the output of `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` somewhere. Nautilus has several `.desktop`. files in `/usr/share/applications` possibly the wrong one is locked to the launcher. Also please look if there are any `nautilus` -related `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 1):

Something in how Ubuntu launches Files might have changed in an update. That means that the launched Files doesn't have the exact same command line as the linked Files.

You could probably fix it by right-clicking the opened folder, select `Lock to launcher`, and the removing the original, normal Files icon by right-clicking it, and selecting `Unlock from launcher`. Then you move the "new" icon up to the position of the old icon, and it should work as before.